# ASP.NET MVC 5 - GeneratePasswordResetToken with custom user table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have a table 'user' with the following fields:

- id
- username
- password
- salt
- folder_files
- active

The password is obtained using Rfc2898DeriveBytes. I would like to allow the user to change his password. I read the this guide:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

I would like to use the GeneratePasswordResetToken. How can I use this method (and therefore also ASP.NET Identity) with che 'user' table (also maintaing the use of Rfc2898DeriveBytes for password hasing)? Can I avoid using the AspNetUsers table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible. However, the AspNetUsers is customizable, as the Password Hasher.